# Lack of a few tabs in vs express for windows phone

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I want to make a trial of my app. I base on info from this site 
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-Windows-Phone-7-Trial-Application-Implementation-and-Best-Practices

but it is written for c# users. My app is written in vb.net language.

I've got a problem with step 5. While making app with vb.net there are 4 tabs (application,debug,compile,references) and while making app with c# there are these 5 tabs you can see on image. I don't know how to do the 5 step when my app is based on vb language...

I swear I won't make app based on vb.net anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the conditional compilation symbols?

If so, go in the 'Compile' tab, click on 'Advanced Compile Options', and define your symbols in the "Custom constants" text box.

For instance, to go on with the tutorial you linked, to define the 'TRIAL' symbol, just type:

```
TRIAL=true
```

[image: Constants]

Then you should be able to conditionally enable pieces of code using those symbols, like in the tutorial:

```
#If TRIAL Then
        IsTrial = True
#End If
```